# FragmentPagerAdapter with an ArrayListFragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager

EDIT: I figured it out, thanks

I have been trying forever now to implement separate ListViews in each of my ViewPager's pages. I understand [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentListArray.html) pretty well, but it only creates one ListView that is used for each page.

I would like to be able to have multiple ListViews in each page, from which I can control what happens onClick for each page's ListView. I have my app working with one ListView (like in the tutorial), but I have been struggling badly with multiple.

My code is posted below and I have tried a ton of different things and I just need to move on in my development. Thanks for the help

```
private static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        TitleProvider {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Arrays.TITLES.length;
    }

    public String getTitle(int position) {
        return Arrays.TITLES[position];
    }

}

public static class ArrayListFragment extends ListFragment {
    int mNum;

    /**
     * Create a new instance of CountingFragment, providing "num" as an
     * argument.
     */
    static ArrayListFragment newInstance(int num) {
        ArrayListFragment f = new ArrayListFragment();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    /**
     * When creating, retrieve this instance's number from its arguments.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Arrays.accTEAMS));
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Log.i("FragmentList", "Item clicked: " + id);
    }
}
```

This is one of my ListFragments:

```
public class ACCfragment extends ListFragment {
View v;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Arrays.accTEAMS);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

}
```

Comment: Could you tell us what API version you're using and which support packages you're using (if any)? The rules for the FragmentPagerAdapter can vary according to these versions.

Comment: Would you like to share your solution with us?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Log.i("FragmentList", "Item clicked: " + id);
    switch(mNum){
       case 1:
        //do what you want for first page
        Log.i("FragmentList", "Page 1: Item clicked: " + id);
        break;
       case 2:
       //do what you want for second page;
       Log.i("FragmentList", "Page 2: Item clicked: " + id);
       break;
       default:
       //default case;
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem I have though. I'm having trouble serving up separate ListViews for each page

Comment: put that same switch in the public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) method. For each one return a different xml. Just make sure you keep track of which page you are on very well, or you will be fc'ing a lot.

Comment: But since I'm using different ListView Fragments, then I don't have separate xml files for each. How do I return each fragment?

Answer (score 0):

you must use bundle to send params between fragments.

sending from Fragment1:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("my_integer",_stationId);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), Fragment2.class.getName(), args);
ft.replace(R.id.layout, fragment);
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft.commit();
```

receiving and getting in Fragment2:

```
getArguments().getInt("my_integer")
```

Comment: I'm not exactly trying to send anything between my fragments.. just trying to display different ListView Fragments on each page in my viewpager